# AdSense data through Google Analytics API

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics, google-api

I have successfully implemented Google Analytics API in my Laravel app following the (rather complex) documentation. When creating this metrics object, I get the response from server, no problem there:

```
$sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
```

However, this is the data I need:

[image]

So then I figured I need some other metrics inside to get the data I need and I searched on the official [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#q=source&cats=user,session,traffic_sources,adwords,goal_conversions,platform_or_device,geo_network,system,social_activities,page_tracking,content_grouping,internal_search,site_speed,app_tracking,event_tracking,ecommerce,social_interactions,user_timings,exceptions,content_experiments,custom_variables_or_columns,time,doubleclick_campaign_manager,audience,adsense,ad_exchange,doubleclick_for_publishers,doubleclick_for_publishers_backfill,lifetime_value_and_cohorts,channel_grouping,related_products,doubleclick_bid_manager,doubleclick_search) for anything related to `source`, but which ever I used from the list I would get the following response:

```
"""
{\n
  "error": {\n
    "code": 400,\n
    "message": "Unknown metric(s): ga:source\nFor details see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets.",\n
    "errors": [\n
      {\n
        "message": "Unknown metric(s): ga:source\nFor details see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets.",\n
        "domain": "global",\n
        "reason": "badRequest"\n
      }\n
    ],\n
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"\n
  }\n
}\n
"""
```

Is there a way for me to fetch the data I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wants an answer, I have solved it by using:

```
//Create the Dimensions object.
$dimensions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$dimensions->setName("ga:source");
```